Difficulty at solving the second order partial differential equation $u_{xx} -3u_{xt} - 4u_{tt}=0$
I'm trying to solve the PDE : $u_{xx} -3u_{xt} - 4u_{tt}=0$ subject to condition $u(x, 0) = \phi (x)$ and $u_t(x, 0) = \psi (x)$
I've found the two characteristics $\xi = t - x$ and $\eta = t + 4x$ so that the equation can be in the canonial form $u_{\xi \eta} = 0$ and I know the solution will be in the form of
$$u(x, t) = A(t-x) + B(t + 4x)$$
and with the substituted inital value as
$$u(x, 0) = A(-x) + B(4x) = \phi (x)$$
$$u_t(x, 0) = A'(-x) + B'(4x) = \psi (x)$$
but now I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help (or mistakes that I've made)?

There's no such thing as $A_t$ and $B_t$, that's just $A'$ and $B'$. Can you turn your $\phi$ equation into one that looks similar? Then maybe you have a system you can solve for the unknowns $A$ and $B$.

I get what I must do but care to elaborate what do you mean by "no such thing as $A_t$ and $B_t$"? I thought you can't do that with multivariable function.

$A$ and $B$ are not multivariable functions.

Oh yeah, I was confused haha thanks!

The change of variables should be: $\xi = t-x, \eta = 4t + x$.

Applying the initial conditions to the general solution
$$
u(x,t)=A(t-x)+B(t+4x), \tag{1}
$$
we obtain
$$
u(x,0)=A(-x)+B(4x)=\phi(x), \tag{2} 
$$
$$
u_t(x,0)=A'(-x)+B'(4x)=\psi(x)
\implies -A(-x)+\frac{1}{4}B(4x)=\Psi(x)+C, \tag{3}
$$
where $\Psi(x):=\int_0^x\psi(s)\,ds$ and $C$ is an arbitrary constant.
Adding $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get
$$
\frac{5}{4}B(4x)=\phi(x)+\Psi(x)+C \implies B(\xi)=\frac{4}{5}\left[\phi\!\left(\frac{\xi}{4}\right)+\Psi\!\left(\frac{\xi}{4}\right)+C\right].
\tag{4}
$$
Eqs. $(2)$ and $(4)$ then yield
$$
A(\xi)=\phi(-\xi)-B(-4\xi)=\frac{1}{5}\phi(-\xi)-\frac{4}{5}\Psi(-\xi)-\frac{4}{5}C. \tag{5}
$$
Substituting $(4)$ and $(5)$ in $(1)$, we finally obtain
$$
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{5}\phi(x-t)+\frac{4}{5}\phi\!\left(x+\frac{t}{4}\right)
+\frac{4}{5}\left[\Psi\!\left(x+\frac{t}{4}\right)-\Psi(x-t)\right]. \tag{6}
$$
